# How to create facebook kind of comment for my blog

Tags: asp.net

I am using C# asp.net. I want to implement a commenting system which is similar to facebook commenting system look & feel. Please give your inputs.

Comment: It is not asp.net MVC but asp.net forms. Thanks.

Comment: Find a good designer. Find a really good frontend developer. Find a decent SQL developer. Forget about WebForms. Learn MVC. Then connect the dots.

Comment: @atornblad - I completely disagree. Why forget about WebForms and learn MVC?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What approach did you take? What were your problems?

Comment: @ThePower Because WebForms has done more to damage the web development community than IE4-7 by allowing people to develop for the web without knowing how the web actually works.

Comment: @atornblad so everyone should be spoon fed and use MVC, I always structure my applications and create relevant controls, I don't need someone else to do that for me.

Comment: @ThePower So you manually create all html, but you use WebForms? You mean you don't use any of the `<asp:*>` controls, but write your own all the time? Then you **should** use MVC.

Comment: @atornblad - Manually create all the html? No, the designers provide it then I break it up in to Master pages and delegate it throughout my pages and controls. I do use <asp:..> controls, frequently. Alongside my own listing controls (containing many <asp:..> controls) and others that I will re-use throughout the application. I like to be in full control of what I can achieve.

Comment: @ThePower - then you are the one being spoon-fed, and not in control. However, I've had this discussion too many times. Nobody ever wins an argument on the internet. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to storing,retrieving and displaying comments yes asp.net controls come into use.
Other things being done, to accept a comment and display existing ones for that object (may be post) I would do:
    **1**: `Retrieve the comments for that object from database`. (easiest way 
     is to use SqlDataSource and set Select, Insert and Delete commands)
    **2**: `Use ListView control to display the retrieved data` . Remember ListView should be customized to fit you need

Other databound controls are also usable. With these rich controls this task should be easy. Play with the templates these controls offer you and you can achieve almost any database related task.
Design and styling are sufficiently supported and still CSS + can be easily integrated.